# Enter url code javascript player?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put url even youtube,vimeo or what ever, then video is playing. Please tell me that player all in one like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: like 'http://vimeo.com/20732587' or 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTasT5h0LEg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty plugin in JQuery to display a video , just have to type it in google.

Look here , there is already lots of choices.

http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/multimedia-jquery-plugins/best-jquery-video-plugins/

Comment: in this url i need this (10. CeeBox) but when i click download shows "The requested page could not be found."

Comment: downloaded from main site thaks dear.